# Can you password protect html pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have a question about html/JavaScript/PHP, I want to be able to view a few pages only if I fill in the right password, but I don't want that you have to put the password in on every private page you visit.

For example:

pages:

- Login.html
- PrivatePage1.html
- PrivatePage2.html

Now you can just go to: 'www.mywebsite.com/PrivatePage1.html' and you don't have to give a password, so is there a way to check if they already logged in on 'Login.hmtl'

My code on 'Login.html'

https://hastebin.com/egehaboxig.js

```
password();

function password() {
    var userPassword;
    var myPassword = "a";

    userPassword = prompt("Enter the password:");

    if(userPassword == myPasswordfun) {
        alert('Correct, press ok to enter the site.');
    }else if(userPassword == null) {
        window.location ="http://www.google.com";
    }else {
        alert('Incorrect');
        password();
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: you understand that everybody is able to view source of your html page and figure out password, right?

Comment: You need a session variable.

Comment: That is like the most inefficient password protection, as anyone can see the password in the source view. It is however possible to store and check cookies in JavaScript. You could store a `logged_in`-Cookie for one hour (or however long you want the user to stay logged in) to achieve what you want. Real protection has to be done server-side though. Further reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: There are actually two ways.. if u wanna do it professionally . Then use php concept  and convert all HTML pages to php pages. And make use of seession variable there. Or simply in JavaScript use, localstorage.. but this is not fully secure..

Comment: @Shubhranshu Your way #1 should not be written as "php". Any server-side language will do.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, i used the "php" just because the OP has tagged his question with "php" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using `localStorage` in Javascript because anyone could manually authenticate themselves on the client-side (in their browser). Really the only option for secure password handling is server-side authentication.

PHP has a built-in variable `$_SESSION` for handling this. To begin, you must start a session on the server with the `session_start()` command. Once the user enters a password, you can validate it and then set the `$_SESSION['valid'] = TRUE`. We can check if the user has validated with the following function.

```
public function is_valid() {
    //Returns true if session is valid, otherwise returns false.
    if( isset( $_SESSION['valid'] ) ) {
      return $_SESSION['valid'];
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
}
```

The session ends when the user closes their browser window.

The passwords themselves should really be stored as a hash in a database. This will prevent anyone, including the webmaster, from accessing the password directly. Once the passwords are hashed, you can hash the user input and compare the two hashes. If they match, you know they entered the correct password.

Comment: I think the first reason why you shouldnt use LocalStorage is not entirely true but using PHP $_SESSION is indeed more safe

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store their successful login somewhere (could be server which is most secure) or could be on the client (less secure).

Several mechanisms will work, but, on the client, **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** is the simplest.

After a successful login, you set a value into `localStorage`, like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("loggedIn", "true");
```

And, on each page that you want to check for logged in, you'd write:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true"){
    // user is logged in
} else {
    // user is not logged in
}
```

Comment: And, of course, this will not work if the client doesn't support localStorage...

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Of course. Nor, will any client-side mechanism if it is turned off.

Comment: Yeah - I just feel that recommending localStorage as a sole solution for something like this is... bad. One should strive to teach good solutions. The solutions works, by all means, but if localStorage isn't supported, it should fall back to something else, or preferably use a server-side something instead.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I didn't recommend `localStorage` as the sole solution and I did point out that it is not secure.